# Geolocation Working on Laptop but Not on Smartphone

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Does anyone know why this doesn't work on a smartphone (Testing on Android), but works on a computer (Tested on a macbook).

Basically when user clicks on a button, the browser will ask for location permission. Works fine on laptop browser, but not on a smartphone.

```
// calling geolocation on click
myButtonElement.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
});

const error = (errorObj) => {
  // handle error
};

const success = (position) => {
  // call weather api etc...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and this is what I did:

First make sure you have updated chrome browser on your device.

1. started Location service of mobile device 1st
2. called the `window.onload = () => getLocation()` function onLoad

By doing this it asked me about permission and worked out well.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  getLocation()
  
  // or
  // calling geolocation on click
  // myButtonElement.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  //  evt.preventDefault();
  //  getLocation()
  // });
}

const successHandler = (position) => { 
  alert(position.coords.latitude) 
  alert(position.coords.longitude)
}

const errorHandler = (errorObj) => { 
  alert(errorObj.code + ": " + errorObj.message); 
}

const getLocation = () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 
    successHandler,
    errorHandler, 
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true, 
      maximumAge: 10000
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It'll work if I turn on GPS on my device first. But if GPS is off, it should alert if use wants to share location.

Comment: It does not if you already refused or accepted. On chrome, you can click on the lock on the left of the address bar and reset the permissions